# Persistent undo erases my file

Tags: neovim, undo-redo

I have been trying to get persistent undo to work for over a day now. I keep having a quite unusual bug. I tried the following:

```
" Let's save undo info!
if !isdirectory($HOME."/.vim")
    call mkdir($HOME."/.vim", "", 0770)
endif
if !isdirectory($HOME."/.vim/undo-dir")
    call mkdir($HOME."/.vim/undo-dir", "", 0700)
endif
set undodir=~/.vim/undo-dir
set undofile
```

I then open an existing file make a few edits and close the file.
Open the file and type 'u' - The entire buffer is emptied.

Then looking through the documentation I found this snippet:

```
au BufReadPost * call ReadUndo()
au BufWritePost * call WriteUndo()
func ReadUndo()
  if filereadable(expand('%:h') . '/UNDO/' . expand('%:t'))
    rundo %:h/UNDO/%:t
  endif
endfunc
func WriteUndo()
  let dirname = expand('%:h') . '/UNDO'
  if !isdirectory(dirname)
    call mkdir(dirname)
  endif
  wundo %:h/UNDO/%:t
endfunc
```

This seems to work better, but I am still getting an undo at the beginning of
every file that removes all content (i.e. pressing u to many times results in
an empty file no matter what I started with) - is there a way to avoid this?

My version info:

```
NVIM v0.4.3
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -O2 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/build/neovim/src/build/config -I/build/neovim/src/neovim-0.4.3/src -I/usr/include -I/build/neovim/src/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim/src/build/include
Compiled by builduser

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you [edit] your Q and give more detail as to what exactly is happening? e.g., you edit a file, save-and-quit, and when you edit again, pressing `u` does what exactly? FWIW, in my vimrc I use (the linebreak-ed equivalent of)  `set undofile undodir=~/.undo
if !isdirectory(expand(&undodir))
  call mkdir(expand(&undodir), "p")
endif
`

Comment: Was I not clear it empties my file?

Comment: I was giving an example. The sequence of steps, the results, and the expected results are somewhat lacking in clarity, yes.

Comment: @d-ben-knoble I tried this: `set undofile undodir=~/.undo if !isdirectory(expand(&undodir)) call mkdir(expand(&undodir), "p") endif` But it resulted in the same result as my first example (deletes the buffer when trying to undo anything)

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was. It was caused by a plugin:

auxiliary/vim-layout

I'm not sure why it causes such strange behavior, but I have uninstalled it and now my undo history works fine.